# mysql create view from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I want create view from tabel admin, akademik, dosen and mahasiswa,
in this view there are have admin, password and id level columns.

have tried this query, but the result is erorr.

```
CREATE VIEW view_user AS
    SELECT admin.id_level, admin.username, admin.password, akademik.id_level, akademik.username, 
    akademik.password, dosen.id_level, dosen.username, dosen.password, mahasiswa.id_level, 
    mahasiswa.username, mahasiswa.password
FROM admin a
    INNER JOIN akademik b on (a.id_level=b.id_level) AND (a.username=b.username) AND (a.password=b.password)
    INNER JOIN dosen c on (b.id_level=c.id_level) AND (b.username=c.username) AND (b.password=c.password)
    INNER JOIN mahasiswa d on (c.id_level=d.id_level) AND (c.username=d.username) AND (c.password=d.password)
ORDER BY 1;
```

I want results like this
[image: I want results like this]

How can I do that? Can somebody help me

Comment: What is the error? What is the table layout of your four tables?

Comment: without thebasic data structure it is difficult to get to your result

Comment: oh i'm sory
error in the query above like this :

 Unknown column 'admin.id_level' in 'field list'

Comment: First whenever creating a view you need to use aliases for fields. So: select admin.id_level as admin_level, dosen.id_level as dosen_level. This is because VIEW can only show select output with unique field names and this is the first error you will encounter. Try to fix that first.

Comment: this means admin table does not have id_level column, you also use aliases for tables so in select use aliases so not admin.id_level but a.id_level.

Comment: each of the 4 tables has an id_level, username, password column.

Comment: but your select makes no sense, because from your conditions, you are looking for users who are in all tables having same credentials in each table, meaning you are looking for duplicates that are located in all 4 tables. meaning that your select needs onyl fields from the master table, the admin table.

Comment: Note that queries against views in MySQL have limited access to underlying indexes rendering them, in my *view* almost useless

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a Inner JOIN on id_level, user_name and password (generally not advised) you don't have to display these 3 columns from all 4 tables, as your desired output is only 3.

```
CREATE VIEW view_user AS
    SELECT admin.id_level, admin.username, admin.password
FROM admin a
    INNER JOIN akademik b on (a.id_level=b.id_level) AND (a.username=b.username) AND (a.password=b.password)
    INNER JOIN dosen c on (b.id_level=c.id_level) AND (b.username=c.username) AND (b.password=c.password)
    INNER JOIN mahasiswa d on (c.id_level=d.id_level) AND (c.username=d.username) AND (c.password=d.password)
ORDER BY 1;
```

Additionally you can remove the order in view creation and do it when querying your view, like this

```
Select * from view_user order by 1;
```